# I'm a student at ABC University or I'm a student in ABC University?

Tags: grammar

I do not know which I should use. I want to explain that I am a current student at/in that university.

Comment: These days 'at' in British English, although before about 1950 you saw 'in the University of XXX' sometimes, especially for lecturers and professors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **at** when talking about the university as a whole:

> I'm a student at ABC University.

Use **in** when referring to a specific school, department or part of the university:

> I'm a student in the school of medicine at ABC University.

> He's a student in the art department at ABC College.

Comment: Thank you it was very informative and helpful